# Combination with multiplicity

Tags: combinatorics

In how many different ways can I order a set like {A,...,A,B,...B,C,...C,...}?
That is,
Imagine we have this array: (A,A,B). Then, I can reorder it in 3! but some of the resulting arrays will be the same. Actually, I can re-order them just like:

```
(A,A,B)
(A,B,A)
(B,A,A)
```

That is, 3 different ways so every array is different from each other.

If I have (A,A,B,B):

```
(A,A,B,B)
(A,B,A,B)
(B,A,A,B)
(B,A,B,A)
(B,B,A,A)
(A,B,B,A)
```

That is, 6 different ways.

So, in general, if I have an array where symbol A appears Ka times, symbol B appears Kb,...
In how many ways can I order it? Computationally, I could just create a matrix with all the permutations and then find and erase all the equal rows (except one), so that the number of rows will be my desired number. But I'd like to do it mathematically, since the length of the initial vector is really big.

Thanks!

Comment: you have forgotten $(A,B,B,A)$

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is the length of the array and for $i=1,...,k$ you have $n_{i}$ times symbol $i$, then the number of ways equals: $$\frac{n!}{n_{1}!\cdots n_{k}!}$$

Here $n_{1}+\cdots+n_{k}=n$

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the [multinomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Number_of_unique_permutations_of_words) that generalizes the binomial coefficient.  If you have $m$ distinct letters and $n$ letters all together (counted with multiplicity), $k_1$ of the first letter, $k_2$ of the second, etc., so
$$
k_1 + k_2 + \cdots k_m = n,
$$
then you have
$$
{n \choose k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_m} = \frac{n!}{k_1! \; k_2! \; \cdots \; k_m!}
$$
possible rearrangements.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [multinomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution).

---

Let us take for an example $\{A_1, A_2, B\}$.

There are $3!$ ways (not $2^3$ as you seem to think) to put them in order if you can distinguish between s. However, $A_1 A_2 B$ is the same as $A_2 A_1 B$, as you noted. Since we count each sequence twice as much as we would like, we just divide $3!$ by $2$. $$3!/2 = 3.$$

---

Similarly, for $\{A_1, A_2, B_1, B_2\}$, we have $4!$ ways to order them initially, but if we consider $A_1$ and $A_2$ indistinguishable and $B_1$ and $B_2$ indistinguishable, then there are $$\frac{4!}{2\cdot 2} = 6$$ ways, because we originally counted each sequence $2 \cdot 2$ times more than we would have liked to. (For example, $A_1 B_1 A_2 B_2$, $A_1 B_2 A_1 B_1$, $A_2 B_1 A_1 B_2$, and $A_2 B_2 A_1 B_1$ are all the same.)

---

So in general, if you have, as you asked, $\{A_1, \ldots, A_{K_a}, B_1, \ldots, B_{K_b}\}$, then there are $(K_a + K_b)!$ ways to order them, and we count each sequence $K_a! K_b!$ times more than we would have liked. So there are $$\frac{(K_a+K_b)!}{K_a! K_b!}$$
total ways.

Note: Finding a way to list all such unique arrays is a different story from counting, however.